# Mysql MATCH AGAINST not working when finding string with at . (DOT)

Tags: mysql

We want to search M.Sc in record using match against mysql query

we are trying following query

```
SELECT  education 
FROM `table` 
where MATCH (education) AGAINST ("B.Sc" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But show no result, but when we use normal Diploma then working good

How we can search and get result when string search have DOT

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: That isn't a real word. Full-text indexes are not designed to find arbitrary strings. Can't you use regular `=` or `LIKE` operators for that?

Answer (score 1):

You (probably) can't: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

> The built-in `FULLTEXT` parser determines where words start and end by looking for certain delimiter characters; for example,   (space), `,` (comma), and `.` (period).

You can create a plugin to replace the parser, but that's another beast (although it's possible someone already created). Not to mention it would have other consequences, for instance: "I like potato." being divided into "I", "like" and "potato." (with the dot as part of the 'word').

Anyway, because of that, B.Sc is interpreted as two words: "B" and "Sc". And, because of `innodb_ft_min_token_size` (if using InnoDB) or `ft_min_word_len` (if using MyISAM), which defaults to 3 and 4 respectively, they're ignored because they're too short.

As pointed out in comments, in this case you're better off using standard comparisons (`=` or `LIKE`).

Comment: but the problem is like is slower than match query. in past we used like query but one of db admin told us to use match query in compare to like query. we are using innodb

Comment: if you recomand like query then can you tell me best way ( query ) to use like to search B.Sc in content which result fast and not increase load on server

Comment: @gaurav The problem is that you cannot use an index to find substrings, just like you can easily find `telephone` in a dictionary but not `leph`. A full-text index solves a very specific use case (finding words from human languages) which is not 100% your use case. Being a hack, it fails to meet some needs.

Comment: @gaurav I think you need an entirely different approach. Preprocess your data, extract individual values you're interested in, store them elsewhere, index that.